# Can i have any persist in a process in process pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, process

i'm trying to use rule and process pattern in my project.
in a article i find this :

> A process is defined as a series of actions in which one or more
>   inputs are used to produce one or more outputs.

now my question is :

can i have any persist in database in a process,in this case my output can be persist result ?or we should return some output 
then persist that output in other place.

Comment: Database should store the output of the process.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya thank you for replying.

Comment: Yes... Process should be independent of source and destination of the data. It should only do process. Later you can change the storage of output to something else instead of database without any impact on the process parts.

Comment: thank you.its great tip.if you add your comment as answer i'll accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any pattern you use should be as independent as possible.

In your case the process should not be worrying about from where data comes and where the output goes.

It should be agnostic of input and output method. So in short you should not be storing data to database as part of the process.

With this approach you can later change the input and output sources without impacting or chancing the process.

Comment: what if i use Repository pattern.with repository pattern we have no worrying about data base !